# Loop through multidimensional array and cast value to float

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, casting

I have the following multidimensional array. Notice that payment_amount, payment_interest, and payment_principle are strings. I need to cast these values to floats. I am getting all twisted around, can someone suggest a foreach() that will accomplish this please?

```
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'payment_date' => string '2015-01-01' (length=10)
      'payment_amount' => string '159609.00' (length=9)
      'payment_interest' => string '26697.78' (length=8)
      'payment_principle' => string '132911.22' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'payment_date' => string '2015-02-01' (length=10)
      'payment_amount' => string '159609.00' (length=9)
      'payment_interest' => string '25039.44' (length=8)
      'payment_principle' => string '134569.56' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'payment_date' => string '2015-03-01' (length=10)
      'payment_amount' => string '159609.00' (length=9)
      'payment_interest' => string '23356.20' (length=8)
      'payment_principle' => string '136252.80' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'payment_date' => string '2015-04-01' (length=10)
      'payment_amount' => string '159609.00' (length=9)
      'payment_interest' => string '21653.04' (length=8)
      'payment_principle' => string '137955.96' (length=9)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'payment_date' => string '2015-05-01' (length=10)
      'payment_amount' => string '159609.00' (length=9)
      'payment_interest' => string '19929.96' (length=8)
      'payment_principle' => string '139679.04' (length=9)
```

Comment: php is loosely typed, do your really need to change the type? show us how your useing the data

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: Yes, because I'm using a package that is taking the array and exporting to an Excel format. When I open the downloaded file in Excel is seeing the data type as text and the formatting as currency isn't working.

Comment: foreach($payments as $record) {
                foreach($record as $key => $value) {
                    $payments[$key] = (float) $value;
                    $payments[$key] = (float) $value;
                    $payments[$key] = (float) $value;
                }
            }

Comment: sounds like an issue woth the code your using to create the excel file

Comment: You shoud then cast during the excel generation, much easier...

Comment: Dagon, that is the first place I looked and I can manually create an array with floats and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
foreach($array as $k=>$arr)
{
    $array[$k]['payment_amount']    = (float) $arr['payment_amount'];
    $array[$k]['payment_interest']  = (float) $arr['payment_interest'];
    $array[$k]['payment_principle'] = (float) $arr['payment_principle'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$a) {
    $a['payment_amount']    = (float) $a['payment_amount'];
    $a['payment_interest']  = (float) $a['payment_interest'];
    $a['payment_principle'] = (float) $a['payment_principle'];
});
```

OR

```
foreach ($arr as &$a) {
    $a['payment_amount']    = (float) $a['payment_amount'];
    $a['payment_interest']  = (float) $a['payment_interest'];
    $a['payment_principle'] = (float) $a['payment_principle'];
}
```